# Where can i run my code in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, i am trying to write my first C# "Hello World" Program in visual studio, however when i want to see the output of the code (or simply just run it), i can't because i can find the run option, i have tried ctrl + f5, and many other options, however it didn't worked any suggestions? Here's a picture of my visual studio.[image]

Comment: Normally you can start your programm with pressing the Green Button. But it seems your file is loose and not conntected to a project.

Comment: I would look into this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019. To understand how to make a console application.

Answer (score 3):

Check this guide [Tutorial: Create a simple C# console app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019)

> 1. Open Visual Studio 2019.
> 2. On the start window, choose Create a new project.
> 3. On the Create a new project window, enter or type console in the search box. Next, choose C# from the Language list, and then choose Windows from the Platform list.
> 4. In the Configure your new project window, type or enter Calculator in the Project name box. Then, choose Create.

And then to run:

> Choose the green Start button next to Calculator to build and run your program, or press F5.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you created empty solution. You don't have any output, i.e. process of compilation of your solution does not produce any executable (exe) or library (dll).

In order to run any code is to produce one of the above. In order to do that you have to have project created.

To do so, you have to (in your case) right click solution and choose "Add -> New Project" option. This will show you pop up allowing you to choose which project you want to add, choose just basic type of project, which is "Console app". There you will have class with static method `Main` which is the entry point for your app.

Code inside `Main` method will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created a project. You've got no executable and no ability to build one. I don't know if you've worked with other languages before or not (perhaps ones which are interpreted and/or have no specific structure to them), but C#/.NET programs require a particular structure in order to build and execute. You can't just create a random C# file on its own and execute it.

Instead, create a new Console Application project (from the File -> New Project menu) and give it a name.

That will auto-generate a Program.cs file, which contains the Main method which is the entry point of your program when it's executed. From there you can write code in there, create other methods in that class if you need to, and you can also add other files containing classes etc. into your project.

---

(There are, as you'll see, also quite a lot of other project types you can create depending on the kind of application you want - and also some types which are just for code libraries and not full applications.)

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Run a C# program in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/run-program?view=vs-2019)

The project should contain a C# file with a Main method, and its output should be an executable (EXE), you have created an empty solution with no such files.